# Gallery View will not display full ImageView when image selected

Tags: android, android-gallery

I have this problem when coding a gallery view in Android. The images appear (as expected) in the top screen of the screen and when they are clicked they say what image is selected (again as expected). However, the image that is selected is not displayed in the imageView. My code is below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Integer[] imageIDs = {
        R.drawable.fourfromunimon,
        R.drawable.fourfromunisat,
        R.drawable.fourfromunisun,  

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);

    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v,
                int position, long id)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "pic" + (position + 1) + " selected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Display the image
            ImageView imageView =
                    (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
            imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
        }
    });
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;

    int itemBackground;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c)
    {
        context = c;

        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(
                R.styleable.Gallery1);
        itemBackground = a.getResourceId(
        R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground,
        0);
        a.recycle();
    }


public int getCount(){
    return imageIDs.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position){
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position){
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView,
ViewGroup parent){
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null){
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(
                ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(
                new Gallery.LayoutParams(450, 200));
    }else{
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
    return imageView;
    }
}
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I do not have the foggiest idea where I could be going wrong.

Comment: is ImageView with android:id="image1" present in activity_main.xml ?

Comment: Why are finding view every time gallery item is clicked? check: `ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
imageView.invalidate();
```

after setting the new image. (Look at [the Drawing section of View in here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)).

Or

```
imageView.invalidateDrawable(imageView.getDrawable());
```

Comment: I have tried both ways as you have described. But it sill does not seem to work. .

Answer (score 0):

My Android tutor(sir) used .png format , try using only .png format and put them all in all drawable folders in project in eclipse, and if it works or not do respond

also after initializing imageIDs

```
Integer[] imageIDs = {
    R.drawable.fourfromunimon,
    R.drawable.fourfromunisat,
    R.drawable.fourfromunisun,  
};
declare gallery and imageview here

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
  you can pass the find view by id here of gallery and imageview
```

and try using this...

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView ivv=new ImageView(context);
    ivv.setImageResource(Garr[position]);
    ivv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    ivv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(450, 200));
    ivv.setBackgroundResource(itembackground);
    return ivv;
}
```

if it works or not do respond